# Is Security configuration required for Glue, to run Athena Queries from Encrypted bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Stored data in Apache Parquet format on S3 with Server side encryption using default KMS key aws/s3.
Created database and Table structure in Glue.
Used Amazon Athena to run SQL queries on the data.

In this condition do I need to enable S3 encryption in Glue Security Configuration?  If yes then can I create separate Security configurations as per databases? Because Every glue database will be attached to different buckets with different encryption keys.

I can run Athena SQL queries to read data without Glue encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the context of your question correctly, you don't need to do anything about the security configuration in Glue. That option is for when Glue writes data, for example in an ETL job.

If your only goal is to query the tables with Athena you only need to ensure that the IAM users or roles you use to query have permissions to use the KMS keys that the data is encrypted with – and since you are able to query the tables it seems that that is already the case.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks @Theo